# How to set windows portable device file attributes programmatically?

Tags: windows, winapi, wpd

My application needs to access a portable device's contents directly without using the [WPD API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Can someone provide some pointers regarding this?

I am using `dbcc_name` as my device interface path. When I tried to call `GetFileAttributes(dbcc_name)` I got an "Access denied" error. How do I appropriately set the ACLs for the portable device?

Do I need to use `SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty()`to set `SPDRP_SECURITY` property?

Thanks.